# Help with SQL-query finding and updating uid's from non-existing users in comment table

Tags: 7, database, search

I need help to make a SELECT from the drupal database.

Two or three tables

- comment
- users
- node (maybe)

I want to find all uid's in the comment table from former users but where the uid>0 in the comment table. uid's for former users but whom don't exist in the users table.

I also would like to make an UPDATE-script that can set all uid's from non-existing users in the comment table to zero "0".

This will solve some of the search indexing problem, where it stopps at certain nodes.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it. Make sure you take a backup before running this:

```
UPDATE {comments} SET uid = 0
WHERE uid > 0
AND cid IN
(
  SELECT cid FROM {comments} AS comment
  LEFT JOIN {users} AS user 
  ON user.uid = comment.uid
  WHERE user.uid IS NULL
)
```